# Filling up orders based on eventdate per ID in R II

Tags: r, autofill

I had a similar question to this previously, and thanks to Ronak Shah, I could solve the problem. However, now I have run into a new problem.

I have the following table. I would like to make a new column called order so that the day when eventdate is not NA, the order of it is zero. And then, I would like to fill up negative consecutively decreasing integers to the previous rows and positive consecutive increasing integers to the below rows per ID. But then I only need the previous three rows to the event date and three rows after the event date, which makes seven rows per eventdate, since the seven rows include the eventdate itself.

Please note that there could be multiple eventdates per ID.

```
+----+------------+-------+
| ID | eventdate  | Value |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | NA         |    10 |
|  1 | NA         |    11 |
|  1 | NA         |    12 |
|  1 | NA         |    11 |
|  1 | 2011-03-18 |    15 |
|  1 | NA         |    17 |
|  1 | NA         |    18 |
|  1 | NA         |    15 |
|  1 | NA         |    20 |
|  1 | NA         |    21 |
|  1 | NA         |    22 |
|  1 | 2011-06-20 |    25 |
|  1 | NA         |    26 |
|  1 | NA         |    25 |
|  1 | NA         |    26 |
|  2 | NA         |     5 |
|  2 | NA         |     6 |
|  2 | NA         |     7 |
|  2 | 2011-05-28 |     9 |
|  2 | NA         |    10 |
|  2 | NA         |    11 |
|  2 | NA         |    15 |
|  2 | NA         |    16 |
|  3 | NA         |    20 |
|  3 | NA         |    22 |
|  3 | NA         |    23 |
|  3 | NA         |    24 |
|  3 | 2012-05-28 |    28 |
|  3 | NA         |    29 |
|  3 | NA         |    25 |
|  3 | NA         |    24 |
|  3 | NA         |    26 |
|  3 | NA         |    24 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

Below is the desired output from the above table.

```
+----+------------+-------+-------+
| ID | eventdate  | Value | order |
+----+------------+-------+-------+
|  1 | NA         |    11 |    -3 |
|  1 | NA         |    12 |    -2 |
|  1 | NA         |    11 |    -1 |
|  1 | 2011-03-18 |    15 |     0 |
|  1 | NA         |    17 |     1 |
|  1 | NA         |    18 |     2 |
|  1 | NA         |    15 |     3 |
|  1 | NA         |    20 |    -3 |
|  1 | NA         |    21 |    -2 |
|  1 | NA         |    22 |    -1 |
|  1 | 2011-06-20 |    25 |     0 |
|  1 | NA         |    26 |     1 |
|  1 | NA         |    25 |     2 |
|  1 | NA         |    26 |     3 |
|  2 | NA         |     5 |    -3 |
|  2 | NA         |     6 |    -2 |
|  2 | NA         |     7 |    -1 |
|  2 | 2011-05-28 |     9 |     0 |
|  2 | NA         |    10 |     1 |
|  2 | NA         |    11 |     2 |
|  2 | NA         |    15 |     3 |
|  3 | NA         |    22 |    -3 |
|  3 | NA         |    23 |    -2 |
|  3 | NA         |    24 |    -1 |
|  3 | 2012-05-28 |    28 |     0 |
|  3 | NA         |    29 |     1 |
|  3 | NA         |    25 |     2 |
|  3 | NA         |    24 |     3 |
+----+------------+-------+-------+
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option where it considers multiple non-NA 'eventdate' per 'ID' - create a function that loops over the index of non-NA elements in 'eventdate' to return the sequence -3:3 for the row indexes

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(eventd) {
     tmp <- rep(NA_integer_, length(eventd))
      i1 <- which(complete.cases(eventd))
      d1 <- purrr::map_dfr(i1, ~ tibble(val = -3:3, ind = (.x + val) 
) %>% 
      filter(ind >=1 & ind <= length(eventd)) %>%
      distinct(ind, .keep_all = TRUE))
      replace(tmp, d1$ind, d1$val)

}
out <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(order = f1(eventdate)) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(order))
```

-output

```
as.data.frame(out)
  ID  eventdate Value order
1   1       <NA>    11    -3
2   1       <NA>    12    -2
3   1       <NA>    11    -1
4   1 2011-03-18    15     0
5   1       <NA>    17     1
6   1       <NA>    18     2
7   1       <NA>    15     3
8   1       <NA>    20    -3
9   1       <NA>    21    -2
10  1       <NA>    22    -1
11  1 2011-06-20    25     0
12  1       <NA>    26     1
13  1       <NA>    25     2
14  1       <NA>    26     3
15  2       <NA>     5    -3
16  2       <NA>     6    -2
17  2       <NA>     7    -1
18  2 2011-05-28     9     0
19  2       <NA>    10     1
20  2       <NA>    11     2
21  2       <NA>    15     3
22  3       <NA>    22    -3
23  3       <NA>    23    -2
24  3       <NA>    24    -1
25  3 2012-05-28    28     0
26  3       <NA>    29     1
27  3       <NA>    25     2
28  3       <NA>    24     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), eventdate = structure(c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 15051L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15145L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 15122L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15488L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), class = c("IDate", "Date")), Value = c(10L, 11L, 
12L, 11L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 15L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 25L, 26L, 25L, 26L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 
29L, 25L, 24L, 26L, 24L)), row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you very much akrun. I have an additional question where there are two event dates for one ID, and the gap between the two event dates is only two days. In this case, the above answer, which is great, won't work anymore because this code tells the computer to get -3:3 range of values with no duplication of rows allowed. 
Now I would like to know if there is any way to generate -3:3 range even in the case where the two eventdates are very close, but still generates -3:3 range of values by ignoring the next or previous eventdates by simply duplicating the existing rows.

Comment: @dodobirdy can you please update with an example so that i can test it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73694153/filling-up-orders-based-on-eventdate-per-id-in-r-iii
@akrun please check the above link!